# XFCE4-Terminal, error loading libraries libpcre

Tags: command-line, xfce, libraries

Out of nowhere, my xfce4 terminal stopped working. When I execute the xfce4-terminal command I get:

```
xfce4-terminal: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre2-8.so.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpcre2-8-0`.

Comment: Perfect! How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: Mark my answer below.

Comment: Got to wait a few minutes before I can mark, will do that in a bit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the faulty library with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpcre2-8-0
```